# How to pass multiple params to a HttpGet method inside of a C# ApiController?

Tags: c#, .net, routes

I have this:

```
public class RuleController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRuleManager _ruleManager;


    // GET: api/Rule/guid
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRule(Guid id)
    {
        var rules = _ruleManager.GetRulesById(id);
        return Ok(rules);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRuleNew(string locale, string pno, string modelYear)
    {
      // do cool stuff with my params
    }

}
```

my route config:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

calling my route:

```
https://localhost:44328/api/rule/GetRuleNew?locale=e?pno=2?modelYear=1
```

I get:

> "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
> 'https://localhost:44328/api/rule/GetRuleNew?locale=e?pno=2?modelYear=1'.",
> "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Rule' that
> matches the request."

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using this instead ? `https://localhost:44328/api/rule/GetRuleNew?locale=e&pno=2&modelYear=1` - using a `&` (instead of a `?`) for the second and subsequent query parameters?

Comment: Wow this forum can sometimes really make you hate copy + paste. @marc_s kindly post this as an answer and thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using this instead ?

```
https://localhost:44328/api/rule/GetRuleNew?locale=e&pno=2&modelYear=1
```

Basically just use a `&` (instead of a `?`) for the second and subsequent query parameters...